# How to manage Page token Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve a list of posts in a facebook-group given a time range, but it requires a **_*paging*_ token** and I'd like to ask you if you know how to create a page token so I can specify this time range.
Thanks in advance.